# lavavel - Undefined Variable $dcategories

Tags: laravel

I an following an on-line tutorial using Laravel - Livewire.
I have spent countless hours in trying to fix an and Undefined variable error. The code and structure is as follows:

Models
DirectoryCategory.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DirectoryCategory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

Livewire Class
AdminDashboardDirectoryCategoryComponent.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin;

use App\Models\DirectoryCategory;
use Directory;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class AdminDashboardDirectoryCategoryComponent extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    public function render()
    {
        $dcategories = DirectoryCategory::paginate(10);
        return view('livewire.admin.admin-dashboard-directory-category-component',['dcategories'=>$dcategories])->layout('livewire/admin.admin-dashboard-directory-category-component');
    }
}
```

view
admin-dashboard-directory-category-component.blade.php

```
<thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>#</th>
                                            <th>Image</th>
                                            <th>Group</th>
                                            <th>Title</th>
                                            <th>Slug</th>
                                            <th>Desc</th>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        @foreach($dcategories as $dcategory)
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>{{$dcategory->id}}</td>
                                                <td><img src="{{asset('frontend.assets/images/dir_categories')}}/{{$dcategory->image}}" width="60" /></td>
                                                <td>{{$dcategory->group}}</td>
                                                <td>{{$dcategory->title}}</td>
                                                <td>{{$dcategory->slug}}</td>
                                                <td>{{$dcategory->desc}}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </tbody>
```

Comment: where did you call livewire component (AdminDashboardDirectoryCategoryComponent.php)?

Comment: Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', config('jetstream.auth_session'), 'verified','authadmin'])->group(function(){
    Route::get('admin/directory-categories',App\Http\Livewire\Admin\AdminDashboardDirectoryCategoryComponent::class)->name('admin.directory_categories');
});

Comment: You are giving same blade file name in view as well as in layout method. May be this is the reason.

Comment: Thanks so much JS TECH.. that was the issue. much appreciated